# Why does the websocket close and open another one?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, websocket, rxjs

I'm having a problem with the ws . In principle I should only have one ws running in the application. But in certain situations (which I don't understand) two things happen:

- More than one ws are started , which have no messages ( only header ) and the last one is the one that connects / subscribes.

[image]

- The ws starts normally ( only 1 ) but suddenly ( without any clear trigger ) unsubscribes from everything and opens another ws . Which by the logic of my application generates me problems.

[image]

Here is the code, this would be the one that creates the Ws with rxjs :

```js
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
/**
 * Create a stomp connection to a given url
 *
 * @param url base url to connect.
 * @param debug (Optional) flag to set debug traces
 */
export function createStompConnection(url: string, debug = false) {
  // create the main connection and return and observable
  const observerStomp: Observable<{ connected: boolean }> = Observable.create(
    (observer: Observer<any>) => {
      // define callbacks for the stomp connection
      const _connectCallback = () => {
        observer.next({ connected: true });
      };
      const _errorCallback = () => {
        observer.next({ connected: false });
      };
      const _closeEventCallback = () => {
        observer.next({ connected: false });
      };

      connectCallback.setCallback(_connectCallback);
      errorCallback.setCallback(_errorCallback);
      closeEventCallback.setCallback(_closeEventCallback);

      // connect to client
      connect();

      // set reconnect delay
      client.reconnect_delay = 1000;
      // return disconnection handle, should be client.disconnect()
      return () => console.warn("client disconnected");
    }
  );
```

and here is where you call and pass the subscribers ( in the redux store ) .

```js
const stomp = createStompConnection(proxyWs);
```

I am not very clear about the management that makes the ws in the front end, so ask me and I will post any part of code that is necessary and I have missed.

Any idea why this behaviour is the expected one? Thx !

Comment: Could it be the server that closes the connection?

Comment: Well it could be , it is a java server with spring , I add the server side code in case it is useful . Although I was leaning more towards the client side. @HMR